# Excel If statement that creates a rolling date range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I use a formula to generate a rolling date range for charts.  The formula is supposed to show "YES" when the date in column A is less than 45 days (or 6 weeks) from today without including the current week.  It stopped working around 1/1/2017.  Are there any other suggestions on a formula that will work correctly when the year changes?

Current Formula that answers "NO" to every row:
`=IF(AND(WEEKNUM(TODAY(),1)-WEEKNUM(A2,1)<=6,WEEKNUM(TODAY(),1)-WEEKNUM(A2,1)>0),"Yes","No")`

[image]

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "stopped working". As near as I can tell, it will always return either "Yes" or "No".

Comment: It now says "No" to everything.

Comment: How can we answer without seeing your data? Note that weeknum gets resets to 1 at the start of the year. If you are subtracting weeknums from last year you will get -negative numbers ...

Comment: I have added what the data looks like.  If the formula will not work across year changes, do you know of a better formula that will work?

Comment: How about checking the year first and then executing your `if()` statement. The function `YEAR(TODAY())` - will return the current year

Comment: Like this:  =IF(AND(YEAR(TODAY))),WEEKNUM(TODAY(),1)-WEEKNUM(A3752,1)<=6,WEEKNUM(TODAY(),1)-WEEKNUM(A3752,1)>0),"Yes","No")?

Comment: You are not accounting for the fact that `WEEKNUM()` rolls over to 1 at the beginning of the new year. If you explain in a bit more detail what you are attempting to accomplish - a rolling date range based on what? - someone may be able to give you a better formula that doesn't rely on `WEEKNUM()`.

Comment: I want it to say YES if the date in column A is < 45 days from Today() not including the current week (so that the charts will only show the data for a full complete week).  The following formula works (regardless of the year) if I do not care about data from incomplete weeks: =IF(A3756<=TODAY(),IF(TODAY()-A3756<45,"Yes","No")).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurred due to the year change and the week number counts starting over.  Below is a formula that worked correctly even when the year changed.

IF(A2<=TODAY(),IF(TODAY()-A2<45,"Yes","No"))

Comment: What's the purpose of the `A2<=Today()`? If you put in a future date, the result will be `FALSE`. Why not just `=IF(Today()-A2<45,"Yes","No")`?

Comment: @Engineer Toast Every year I set up the dates all the way through the current year.  This formula allows me to have a rolling filter for the pivot tables that will not show those dates that are in the future.